# Как добавить bash скрипт в автозагрузку конкретного пользователя

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Есть Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS
Есть bash скрипт
Необходимо добавить этот скрип в автозагрузку, но не от рута, от конкретного пользователя.
Гуглил 2 дня не нашел ответа на этот вопрос

Comment: а в результате какого события в хотите, чтобы запускался ваш сценарий?

Comment: Вот что-то похожее, но не совсем кошерно, целый crontab предлагают тащить https://serverfault.com/a/422951

Comment: Скрипт должен исполнятся при запуске системы

Comment: выполняйте его из любого загрузочного скрипта с помощью sudo

Comment: А у гугла спрашивал следующее: как добавить скрипт в автозагрузку пользователя ubuntu server, скрипт в автозапуск, how to start bash script on boot by user, how to mount on boot ubuntu

Comment: Вообще задача маунтить яндекс диск под пользователем при загрузке. Настраивал по этой инструкции http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/davfs2 и споткнулся в самом конце.

Comment: Mike, нужно что бы скрипт грузился из под конкретного пользователя а не из под рута

Comment: Alexander Zonov, этот вариант видел, но мне он не совсем нравится

Comment: @fibboo, мне кажется, в вашем варианте было бы лучше прописать монтирование WebDav в файле `/etc/fstab`, там же можно и задать параметры типа "пользователь по умолчанию"

Comment: Не помню, как устанавливал `yandex-disk`, но `ps` мне сейчас выдает, что запущен он вот так: `/usr/bin/yandex-disk --tag="1 8 9 12 15 16 19" --proxy="no" --no-daemon="true" --dir="/home/user/Yandex.Disk" --auth="/home/user/.config/yandex-disk/passwd"`. Вы хотите на его папку отдельный девайс замонтировать? Тут пахнет `fstab`.

Comment: "как добавить скрипт в автозагрузку пользователя ubuntu server" второй результат поиска выдал https://losst.ru/kak-dobavit-skript-v-avtozagruzku-ubuntu

Comment: @fibboo Загрузка вся идет из под рута. другой нет. но раз скрипт должен быть с правами пользователя - то мы просто заменяем пользователя перед запуском, а делает это sudo

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустить программу от имени простого пользователя во время старта системы можно с помощью утилиты sudo. Cтрочку на подобие нижеследующей поместите в файл `/etc/rc.local` перед самым выходом.

```
sudo -i -u пользователь /путь/к/вашему/сценарию
```

Если команды sudo нету — установите.

Comment: *Если команды sudo нету — установите* — или [воспользуйтесь программой *su*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/893240/178576)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам необходимо запустить некую программу/скрипт именно при открытии сеанса некоторого пользователя (например - себя), а не запустить эту программу/скрипт во время загрузки системы от имени этого пользователя, то решение очень простое.

Вставьте строку запуска этой программы/скрипта в файл .profile  или .bashrc в домашнем каталоге этого пользователя. Если у Вас есть на то права. Какой именно файл использовать - зависисит от дистрибутива Linux. В принципе они равноправны.

Обратите внимание на точку в начала имени файла. Что бы его увидеть надо выдать команду *ls -a*.

Answer (score 0):

в rc.local  cd /root/ && ./menu.sh

Comment: в вопросе же написано: *но не от рута, от конкретного пользователя*