# Как выполнить программу от имени другого пользователя?

Tags: ubuntu, права, users

В системе несколько пользователей. Захожу на сервер через ssh от имени root.

Вопрос: как запустить скрипт:

```
~# php /пусть_до_файла/1.php
```

от имени пользователя user, залогинившись под пользователем root?

Answer (score 5):

выполнить программу (с опциями/параметрами или без них) от имени указанного пользователя можно:

1. с помощью программы *su* (присутствует в системе обязательно):

   ```
   $ su -l -c 'программа [опции|параметры]' пользователь
   ```

   кавычки — обязательны; одинарные или двойные — в данном случае роли не играет.
2. с помощью программы *sudo* (если установлена):

   ```
   $ sudo -u пользователь программа [опции|параметры]
   ```

здесь `программа [опции|параметры]` — это (для приведённого в вопросе примера) `php /пусть_до_файла/1.php`

---

если программа *su* или *sudo* выполняется от имени пользователя с идентификатором `0` (обычно он имеет имя `root`), то пароль не запрашивается. о разнице между этими программами: [В чём разница между su и sudo?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522691/178576)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел вот такой способ. Надеюсь правильный.

```
~# sudo -u user php /пусть_до_файла/1.php
```